# Running testMyFoo binary within adb shell

Tags: adb

I figure this question comes up often, but here goes:  I have a testMyFoo binary that

1. Is installed on the phone's `/data/local/tmp/` path
2. has appropriate execute permissions
3. requires a series of shared-object libraries (one of them being libc++_shared.so)
4. set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable with the required search paths
5. is built with the correct toolchain+sysroot for the phone (arm64-v8a/android33)

So when I try to execute `./testMyFoo`:

1. It seems to execute
2. It finds my dependent shared-object libs
3. It fails to load libc++_shared.so

I get this error:

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "./testMyFoo": couldn't map "/storage/emulated/0/MLZ/mlz-libs/libc/libc++_shared.so" segment 1: Permission denied
```

From what I've read online, it seems I have to run this through an Android studio project.  I would like to avoid that (for now), and just run my program directly.  Any suggestions?

Thanks, Charles.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the shared internal storage `/storage/emulated/0` is mounted with no execute restriction.

It seems this does not only affect executables but also libraries loaded by executables and thus you get an `Permission denied`.

You should better copy the libraries so that they are located in the same directory as your binary. libraries not together with the binary in `/data/local/tmp`. Then loading the libraries should work.